# Error VS1290: The backplane configuration file is either missing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I'm working on a layered application on VS2010 with TFS 2012, the application has some class library projects, unit tests and an mvc4 web.

This error is appearing on my error list:

`VS1290: The backplane configuration file is either missing, corrupted, or not valid and must be repaired. Otherwise, integrations between designers will no longer function. Repair the Visual Studio installation and try again.`

Doing some searches I found [this](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/540386/vs1290-the-backplane-configuration-file-is-either-missing-corrupted-or-not-valid) but it's closed as not reproducible. I'll appreciate any help provided.

Note the application **is** working, but I'd like to resolve it anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saldy the solution for me was reinstalling Visual Studio.